# Symfony 4.1 OneToMany in test return empty

Tags: testing, phpunit, symfony4

Why in my test not working relationships? For example, one Product have two ProductVariant, but $product->getVariants()->count() return 0, but count($variants) return 2.

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Service\Marketplace\Banggood;

use App\Test\TestCase;
use Nelmio\Alice\Loader\NativeLoader;

class ImportOrderTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_transform()
    {
        $this->loadFixtures();

        $product = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App:Product')->findOneBy(['foreignId' => 93255]);

        $variants = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App:ProductVariant')->findBy(['product' => $product]);

        dd($product->getVariants()->count(), count($variants));

}

protected function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->getService('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
}

protected static function getService($id)
{
    return self::$kernel->getContainer()->get($id);
}

protected function loadFixtures()
{
    $loader = new NativeLoader();
    $objectSet = $loader->loadFile(__DIR__."/../DataFixtures/test/fixtures.yaml");
    foreach ($objectSet->getObjects() as $entity)
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
    }

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

I spent about 4 hours but don't found where is the bug.

fixtures.yaml

```
App\Entity\Product:
  product:
    name: 'Product # 1'
    foreignId: <numberBetween(1,99999)>
    bodyHtml: <text(300)>
    description: '<paragraph(1)>'
    tags: ''
    option1: "Size"
    option2: "Color"

App\Entity\ProductVariant:
  pv{1..2}:
    product: '@product'
    name: 'Variant <current()>'
    grams: <numberBetween(100, 1000)>
    sku: <ean8()>
    option1 (unique): <numberBetween(1, 200)>
    option2: "<randomElement(['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'green', 'white'])>"
```

My fixtures work fine, in database i see one row in products table and two rows in product_variants table.

fragment from App\Entity\Product class

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProductVariant", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $variants;

/**
 * @return Collection|ProductVariant[]
 */
public function getVariants(): Collection
{
    return $this->variants;
}
```

Comment: could you share the orm model also? could be useful the fixture files too

Comment: sure, i shared fragment from fixture and orm class

Comment: Looks like that the variants aren't yet loaded. I'm not so fluent with that specifc ORM but this might be a lazy loading strategy. For your test it's hard to say if this is a true issue, however you should dig on deeper as answering the question will clarify your testing case for you, so you'll learn more about that ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, it was in my fixtures. The right variant of the code below.

```
App\Entity\Product:
  product:
    name: 'Product # 1'
    foreignId: <numberBetween(1,99999)>
    bodyHtml: <text(300)>
    description: '<paragraph(1)>'
    tags: ''
    option1: "Size"
    option2: "Color"
    variants: '@pv{1..2}'

App\Entity\ProductVariant:
  pv{1..2}:
    name: 'Variant <current()>'
    grams: <numberBetween(100, 1000)>
    sku: <ean8()>
    option1 (unique): <numberBetween(1, 200)>
    option2: "<randomElement(['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'green', 'white'])>"
```